# how to make the restapi call to send request and download in wso2 EI

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have link for example 'https://something' provided by client and through postman I have to click on 'send and download' instead only send to make it work
On clicking 'send and download' it downloads file but where as if I click only send it responds 200OK but blank response which is not correct.
I am trying to replicate the same in WSO2 EI, below is my code.
But it is only downloading blank response not the file.
what should be added to make it work like postman to accept 'send and download' option?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="Proxy" startOnLoad="true" transports="http https vfs" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="post" uri-template="https://abcd">
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
                            
            <log>
                <property expression="get-property('axis2', 'HTTP_SC')" name="log-1"/>
             </log>
             <filter regex="200" source="get-property('axis2', 'HTTP_SC')">
                <then>
                    <call>
                        <endpoint>
                            <http method="post" uri-template="https://efgh">
                            </http>
                        </endpoint>
                    </call>
                    <log>
                        <property expression="get-property('axis2', 'HTTP_SC')" name="log-2"/>
                    </log>
                    <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
                    <property name="ClientApiNonBlocking"  value="true" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
                    <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
                    <send>
                        <endpoint>
                            <address uri="vfs:file:///C:/Work"/>
                        </endpoint>
                    </send>
                </then>
            </filter>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

Comment: Can you try to download the file with curl and tell us the headers/options you used in the curl command?

Comment: I will try to use the curl command but right now with postman it works with 'send and download'

Comment: If you're not able to use curl, there should also be the postman console which should print out all infos. https://blog.postman.com/powerful-debugging-with-the-postman-console/

Comment: Please find the details POST https://example.com:yyyy/ddd/download?query=xxx&X-CounterPath-CSRFP=xxxx&groupname=xxx&start=xxx&end=xxx: {
  "Network": {
  },
  "Request Headers": {
    "user-agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.29.0",
    "accept": "*/*",
    "postman-token": "366e6750-5ce1-430a-9733-8e0619e92c97",
    "host": "abc.com:yyyy",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "connection": "keep-alive",
    "cookie": "JSESSIONID=xxx.node0",
    "content-length": "0"
  }

Comment: "Response Headers": {
    "date": "Tue, 14 Jun 2022 07:46:05 GMT",
    "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
    "referrer-policy": "same-origin",
    "x-ua-compatible": "IE=11",
    "strict-transport-security": "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains",
    "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
    "feature-policy": "autoplay 'none'; camera 'none'; microphone 'none'",
    "x-permitted-cross-domain-policies": "none",
    "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block",
    "content-type": "application/zip",
    "content-disposition": "attachment; filename=\"xxx.zip\";",
    "content-length": "716"  }

Comment: Have you tried sending headers like "accept-encoding": "gzip" from WSO2 EI?

Comment: @ycr I have not yet, I will try that. thanku

Comment: @ycr I have tried it but it is still now working